# How to compose url from rxjs `BehaviorSubject`

Tags: angular, rxjs

this is the `BehaviorSubject` getting value:

`private searchClinicByParams$: BehaviorSubject<SearchClinicByParamsProps> = new BehaviorSubject(initialSearchParams);`

here is my method needs to compose the vaues:

```
getParams() {
        const values = this.searchClinicByParams$.pipe(
            map((data) => data)
        );
        console.log('values', values);
    }
```

at present above map not returns any value.

here is my get method:

```
 clinicList$ = this.http
        .get<AddClinicProps[] | null>(
            this.URL +
                `hfs-admin/customer-application/clinics?name=OUS&adminUserName=${this.getParams()}`
        )
        .pipe(
            map((clinics) => clinics),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
```

how can i get return value at `this.getParams()` or what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: @Pycnonotus, though i could not able to return from subscribe

Comment: Hello, @3gwebtrain. You can get value from `BehaviorSubject` using `getValue()` method. For example `const valueOfBS = this.blabla.myBS.getValue();`. Check rxjs documentation - https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject#value

Answer (score 2):

Your `getParams()` function has a misleading name, it doesn't `get` anything since you are not returning anything, I always suggest explicitly setting the return type for your function, in this case, it should be an `Observable` of type `SearchClinicByParamsProps` given your example:

```js
getParams(): Observable<SearchClinicByParamsProps> {
  return this.searchClinicByParams$.asObservable();
}
```

And then, in your function where you are making the HTTP call:

```js
clinicList$ = this.getParams().pipe(
  mergeMap((params) => this.http.get(`${this.url}hfs-admin/customer-application/clinics?name=OUS&adminUserName=${params}}`)),
  catchError(this.handleError)
)
```

I assume somewhere in your application, something is listening to `clinicList$`, so when it subscribes, you will get your response.

Comment: I would like to manipulate the values from `searchClinickByParamsPoprs` then need to return, how to do?

Comment: when I try this, ` return this.searchClinicByParams$.pipe(
            map((data) => {data.countryCodes})
        );` getting object in params

Comment: Try adding parenthesis to the return value like so: `....pipe( map((data) => ({data.countryCodes}) ) );`

Answer (score 0):

There're 2 things not being done right logically.

1. `getParams()` is not returning anything.
2. You are using `getParams()` as if it is returning a `string`

Despite the naming of your functions, you may either

1. Subscribe the value from `searchClinicByParams$` to a local variable and use it in your HTTP request.
2. Return the observable in `getParams()` and pipe it to your HTTP request with one of the mapping operators.